# How to change same combobox in datagridview multiple times in a row?

Tags: c#

I have a combobox in a datagridview and on the first event handling it works fine, when i choose value from the combobox in the other row it also works fine but the problem is when i choose value from the same combobox in the same row two times. On the second event handling it doesn't go to the **" dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing"** method, it directly goes to **"combo_SelectedIndexChanged"** and it causes **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**

```
 private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if(combo != null)
        {
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(combo_SelectedIndexChanged);
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged += combo_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }
    }

    public void combo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            selected = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString();
            LoadData(selected);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Which object is null? SekectedItem? Or is Sender not a ComboBox?

Comment: It's this one Application.Run(new Login()); in the Main()

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the form.designer.cs file and update the pointer for the combobox selectedindexchanged to point to dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing

for example
          this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);

Comment: I get this error "No overload for 'dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing' matches delegate 'EventHandler'" when I add that line of code.